# Redirect URLs with Curly Brackets in it

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have about 30.000 old urls that need to be redirected
I am using excel to obtain a rewrite rule for each URL

My old URLS are using a Unique Identifier in the query string part
Basically I am trying to redirect

```
www.mysite.com/dettagli.asp?ID_S={965c1471-b985-45c1-9d7a-9fcede5711ed}
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/mynewurl.html
```

I can map any UID to the new URLS in excel but rewrite rules so far haven't been successful

I have tried escaping the cury brackets with "\" in front of them, no luck

So far I have tried

```
redirect 301  /dettagli.asp?ID_S={965c1471-b985-45c1-9d7a-9fcede5711ed}
```

and

```
redirect  301  /dettagli.asp?ID_S=\{965c1471-b985-45c1-9d7a-9fcede5711ed\}
```

Comment: do all the urls map to the same new url are is it all 1 for 1? If it's all 30000 urls to one new URL, that's easy to do.

Comment: actually it was not that easy, at least not for me.

Comment: you didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement all redirect rules in php. The only thing you need set up in .htaccess in entry point for php.

Comment: I ended up following your advice. A php page with all the 1 to 1 redirects (takes an ID as inout and redirects to the correct url)

Answer (score 0):

actually it was not that easy, at least not for me.

I think I found a solution using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID_S={2e69bb2d-655e-4488-b6cd-ba6e016db346}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/mynewurl.html? [R=301,L]
```

and so on....

but 30.000 Urls generate 60.000 Rows in htacces which weighs more than 5MB....

I think I 'll reconsider it

Comment: Then I suggest you use a config file instead of .htaccess. rewrites.conf with all the 30000 rewrites in it and include it in your apache config. Then restart apache. That way it's only read once and that's it. .htaccess is read on every request so it will slow down your site.

Comment: Don't use shared. LOL, You have no control. VPS or cloud servers are so cheap these days. $5 or $10/mo and you get complete access including ssh.